# Shortest method to find Min and Max length of word in array

Tags: c#, lambda

I have following array

```
string[] words = { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry", "banana", "mango", "orange", "pineapple" };
```

I want to find the `Max` and `Min` no. of alphabets. e.g. `Max = 9` (for pineapple) and `Min = 5` (for apple)

Which is the shortest method to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx) and [Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx) methods:

```
var min = words.Min(w=> w.Length);  // 5
var max = words.Max(w=> w.Length);  // 9
```

Comment: Beautiful. Didn't even know you could express functional things like that in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient is to simply loop through the strings:

```
int min = Int32.MaxValue;
int max = 0;
foreach (s in words) {
   min = Math.Min(min, s.Length);
   max = Math.Max(max, s.Length);
}
```